# convert string to json array usin json simple library in java

Tags: java, json

I'm looking for a way to convert this String

```
[{"season":"w15","club":"belle-plagne"},{"season":"w15","club":"belle-plagne"},{"season":"w15","club":"belle-plagne"}]
```

that looks like a json array to a json array using the java library **json simple**

Thx in advance,
best regards

Mayes

Answer (score 0):

you should have check out this example url from **json example** first. if you have any specific problem, then you should ask specific question.

http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples

Comment: Agreed, but this would be a better comment than an answer.

Comment: @DavidS Thanks for the heads up. would be more careful in future. :)